# Use custom certificate to authenticate server in php with curl

Tags: php, curl, https

I am trying to connect to an API available through https and that is also implementing client-side authentication via certificates.

I cannot find a way to connect with php using the custom certificate and signature given for the server.

Here is the code that I am using to connect to the API with curl:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . 'server-custom-cert.crt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Those settings do not give any answer from the API (I tried also to convert the server custom certificate to the pem format without any success), whereas when I use those settings without any verification for the peer or the host, I can use the API normally:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

When I look at the info about the session using this:

```
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($info, true) . '</pre>';
```

I get this:

```
Array
(
[url] => https://api.example.com
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 0
[filetime] => 0
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_ip] => 
[primary_port] => 0
[local_ip] => 
[local_port] => 0
[redirect_url] => 
)
```

with an 'httpStatusCode' being null.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what does curl_error($curl) return?

Comment: curl_errors($curl) returns nothing... :(